# Is it expensive to create the Thread object or to actually start the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive).

Now there are various reasons as why creating a thread is expensive, notably the fact that a lot of memory needs to be allocated and the thread needs to be registered.

Now consider this code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new SomeRunnable());
thread.start();
```

Which part of that is the "expensive" part? The line that actually creates the Thread object or the line that starts the thread? Or both? The reason why I am asking is because I am writing the server-component of a game and I am debating if I should create the Thread object as soon as the player connects and start the thread once the player finishes logging in, or should I both create and start the thread after the player finishes logging in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating a `Thread` object is very cheap. You just pay the price of calling the constructor. It's the `start()` method that takes up space (native calls, stack memory, etc.)

On the other hand if you create plenty of threads, consider creating (and starting them) in advance and having a pool. This is already done for you, check out [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class.

Comment: Couldn't agree with this answer more - don't explicitly manage your threads, let the executors framework do it for you.

Comment: If I create a thread when a player connects and I stop (interrupt) it when the player disconnects, what Executor would you suggest I use? And also, by saying, "You just pay the price of calling the constructor." are you implying that the first line is the most expensive of the two?

Comment: @MartinTuskevicius: check out [`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()). And calling a constructor should be very fast, almost free. It's `start()` that takes time and consumes memory.

Answer (score 4):

This really smacks of premature optimization to me.  I really doubt that you are going to see any difference between instantiating or starting the thread earlier rather than later.  If it was 100 threads then I might feel differently.

If you *have* seen performance problems with your application then I would encourage you to use a profiler to discover the real performance sinks.

Comment: I understand that it's a relatively small thing, but it's a matter of changing two lines for me. I would still like to know the better of the two options.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the cost of thread creation, use a Thread pool. I agree with @Gray though. Like a connection pool, a thread pool keeps you from creating things over and over again (and it keeps the number of threads from growing uncontrollably).