# Java Thread creation process flow

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading section ThreadPools section 6.2.3 java concurrency in practice by Brian Goetz. A statement I came across is 
"Reusing an existing thread instead of creating a new one amortizes thread creation and teardown costs."

1) I wanted to get some metrics involved in the java thread creation process which as we know will involve the creation/allocation of a stack and the program counter register to the created thread. Is there a tool/utility/visual vm tracer/jmx bean that I can use for the same which can give me some indicators on memory and time usage for thread creation. Can some one guide me to the same ?

2) Is there a text which can guide me to the whole process of java thread creation in detail which should cover the respective OS calls to windows ?

[Why is creating a Thread said to be expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive) has given me some information, but I wanted to study the internals of java thread creation in detail

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at jconsole which comes with the distribution of the jdk?

Comment: @Shervin - I have looked into jconsole and jvisualvm, since they both support mbeans, I went to ThreadImpl.getThreadAllocatedBytes, is it that the indicator of java stack size ?Also I couldn't find any indicator for time taken for Thread creation ? Also could you help  me on point number 2, I am looking for some great theory on java thread construction process and the concerned OS level calls for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your second question:

> 2) Is there a text which can guide me to the whole process of java
>   thread creation in detail which should cover the respective OS calls
>   to windows ?

This guide, though slightly off topic is great: http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html

And the following book [The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition (google book link)](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/The_Java_Virtual_Machine_Specification_J.html?id=95HzjxTELRkC&redir_esc=y) explains the JVM internals in depth and as such would be my best bet (disclaimer: I had only *skimmed* through the visible parts)

If that is not good enough, you could always [download](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) the source code for the [open jdk (7)](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) and crawl through the code...

An *excerpt* from the open jdk code is this (openjdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\thread.cpp - c'tor):

```
// Base class for all threads: VMThread, WatcherThread, ConcurrentMarkSweepThread,
// JavaThread


Thread::Thread() {
  // stack and get_thread
  set_stack_base(NULL);
  set_stack_size(0);
  set_self_raw_id(0);
  set_lgrp_id(-1);

  // allocated data structures
  set_osthread(NULL);
  set_resource_area(new ResourceArea());
  set_handle_area(new HandleArea(NULL));
  set_active_handles(NULL);
  set_free_handle_block(NULL);
  set_last_handle_mark(NULL);

  // This initial value ==> never claimed.
  _oops_do_parity = 0;

  // the handle mark links itself to last_handle_mark
  new HandleMark(this);

  // plain initialization
  debug_only(_owned_locks = NULL;)
  debug_only(_allow_allocation_count = 0;)
  NOT_PRODUCT(_allow_safepoint_count = 0;)
  NOT_PRODUCT(_skip_gcalot = false;)
  CHECK_UNHANDLED_OOPS_ONLY(_gc_locked_out_count = 0;)
  _jvmti_env_iteration_count = 0;
  set_allocated_bytes(0);
  _vm_operation_started_count = 0;
  _vm_operation_completed_count = 0;
  _current_pending_monitor = NULL;
  _current_pending_monitor_is_from_java = true;
  _current_waiting_monitor = NULL;
  _num_nested_signal = 0;
  omFreeList = NULL ;
  omFreeCount = 0 ;
  omFreeProvision = 32 ;
  omInUseList = NULL ;
  omInUseCount = 0 ;

  _SR_lock = new Monitor(Mutex::suspend_resume, "SR_lock", true);
  _suspend_flags = 0;

  // thread-specific hashCode stream generator state - Marsaglia shift-xor form
  _hashStateX = os::random() ;
  _hashStateY = 842502087 ;
  _hashStateZ = 0x8767 ;    // (int)(3579807591LL & 0xffff) ;
  _hashStateW = 273326509 ;

  _OnTrap   = 0 ;
  _schedctl = NULL ;
  _Stalled  = 0 ;
  _TypeTag  = 0x2BAD ;

  // Many of the following fields are effectively final - immutable
  // Note that nascent threads can't use the Native Monitor-Mutex
  // construct until the _MutexEvent is initialized ...
  // CONSIDER: instead of using a fixed set of purpose-dedicated ParkEvents
  // we might instead use a stack of ParkEvents that we could provision on-demand.
  // The stack would act as a cache to avoid calls to ParkEvent::Allocate()
  // and ::Release()
  _ParkEvent   = ParkEvent::Allocate (this) ;
  _SleepEvent  = ParkEvent::Allocate (this) ;
  _MutexEvent  = ParkEvent::Allocate (this) ;
  _MuxEvent    = ParkEvent::Allocate (this) ;

#ifdef CHECK_UNHANDLED_OOPS
  if (CheckUnhandledOops) {
    _unhandled_oops = new UnhandledOops(this);
  }
#endif // CHECK_UNHANDLED_OOPS
#ifdef ASSERT
  if (UseBiasedLocking) {
    assert((((uintptr_t) this) & (markOopDesc::biased_lock_alignment - 1)) == 0, "forced alignment of thread object failed");
    assert(this == _real_malloc_address ||
           this == (void*) align_size_up((intptr_t) _real_malloc_address, markOopDesc::biased_lock_alignment),
           "bug in forced alignment of thread objects");
  }
#endif /* ASSERT */
}
```

Comment: I have followed Inside the java virtual machine by Bill Venners, it gives me an understanding of the internal data structures . Your post above definitely shows a way and which is to debug the native methods, stuff like start0() in Thread. I think it will help me understand from the code's perspective. Thanks. Though finding a right debugger.