# Why do Android services not run in separate threads?

Tags: android, android-service

Why does a service not run in it's own thread under Android? And what were the design considerations?

Comment: I don't know why it's not running, but you can create service in another process or use IntentService, which running in another thread.

Comment: Sure. I just want to know the resoning, why? Anyone with insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all about Flexibility: I assume you are familiar with so many Frameworks like for example `e.g. Volley, Retrofit etc`. These Frameworks has their own Thread implementation behind scene so if `Service` by default is executed in a separate Thread then it is **overkill**. Why? because the threading is handled by the framework already so why the need to have another thread?

See also [Why is creating a Thread said to be expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive). And put also into consideration that you are doing Threading in an Android device and not into a powerful Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) I think this is that you are looking for.

Comment: How come did they design it this way (I know IntentService)?

Comment: suppose you want to do some background work which is not going to consume too much of CPU time then rather than doing that work in a new thread,you can do it in main thread of your app(with less/no performance degradation). But if u were to something CPU intensive work then doing that in main thread of your application will slow down your application so for that you create a new thread and do the work in the new thread.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you more flexibility. For example you could run each request in a seperate thread with special priorities or you could store the requests in a queue and only start the next thread if the previous one has finished. A IntentService provides a default configuration that in the most cases fits your needs from scratch.(http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Such decisions depend on your use case.