# Looping in Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following two designs of `run` method:

**Approach A**

```
public void run() {
    do {
        //do something
    } while (condition);
}
```

**Approach B**

```
public void run() {

    //do something...

    if (condition) {
       new Thread(this).start();
    }
}
```

The second approach seems cleaner to me, after some debate, I have been told it's not a good idea to use approach two.

Question:

1. What are reasons (if there is any) that I shouldn't be using approach 2?

Comment: Why does the 2nd seem cleaner? I believe it would actually confuse any programmer.

Comment: What have you been told in that debate about why Approach B is not good?

Comment: In approach A you are running a loop until a condition is met and in approach B you start a new thread when a condition is met.??

Comment: Why would you want to create multiple instances of `Thread` when what you want is a loop only?

Comment: @nafas The two approaches don't really do the same thing.You can't compare apples and oranges.

Comment: @Codebender the core logic of program is on top ( its a matter of prefrence really)

Comment: @CKing lol, they both do the same thing over and over until the condition is reached...

Comment: I guess it is quite costly to always create a new thread and then to do the context switch. Therefore, I would prefer approach A.

Comment: They do not. Approach B will loop until the end of time. It only starts a new thread when a condition is met.

Comment: @Arno approach B doesn't have a loop. btw your two sentences contradict each other...

Comment: @nafas How does approach B do the same thing over and over again. The way you have coded approach B simply means that if the condition is met, a new thread will be spawned that will do the work. Where is the loop in case of approach B?

Comment: @CKing mate, they both will do `//do something...` as long as the condition is met

Comment: @CKing: The "loop" exists because that second Thread will spawn a third and so on. Similar in spirit to recursion vs. explicit loop.

Comment: If Approach B does not loop then what are you comparing. They do totally different things. So Approach A loops until a condition is met. Approach B starts a thread when a condition is met.

Comment: @Thilo I see. That's kind of pointless.

Comment: So the idea is that the new Thread would call the run method again? In approach B

Comment: @Arno essentially yes. as Thilo said its similar in spirit to recursion vs loop

Answer (score 4):

You have two things here. A loop, and a method that continuously runs itself again in a new thread until a condition is met (not a loop).

If you need a loop, you would choose the standard normal loop that everyone understands and works perfectly.

If you need to write a weird piece of code that creates new threads for no reason, and makes other developers doubt your skills and understanding, you would go for option B.

There's absolutely no sense in your choice B **unless** there would be something additional like a queue or ThreadPoolExecutor involved for re-invoking the method, so the method would add `this` at the end for invocation at a later time, sort of like a "lazy loop".

Comment: B will behave like a loop where each iteration is run in a new thread. It is  a recursive implementation of a loop. It would have made a lot more sense in Haskell and without the threading though.

Answer (score 1):

Because approach B uses one more thread than approach A. Creating threads is expensive, for a number of reasons @see [Why is creating a Thread said to be expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive)

Approach A is also a little clearer to the reader, IMO. The simplest option usually is.

Comment: Approach B does not use just 2 threads, it uses `N` (could be big). Of course, just 2 at a time. As for expensive, that's relative, depends on how much real work is being done inside of run. And it can be reduced to effectively zero by using a thread pool. But yeah, "the simplest option is usually the best". Don't use Threads, when you don't need to. Use loops for looping.

Comment: Yes I see your point, I guess I meant that B uses one more thread than A. I'll update the answer.

Comment: But B does _not_ use one more thread than A.  Approach A runs in one thread.  Approach B requires one thread for each execution of `//do something`.  Approach B sequentially creates and destroys N threads where the example gives us no idea how large N might be.

Comment: Ok, although there's no indication that `//do something` is iterative. I think this answer is still ok, although I agree a Thread Pool is usually best with this kind of design.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd option creates a new thread every time it is iterated, so it ends up being unnecessarily costly, especially when option A does the same thing but doesn't create new threads for every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The only good use-case I can find for Pattern B is if there is a significant delay before you want to re-run the method. For example for some kind of polling system that is supposed to run every X minutes until the system is being shut down.

In that case, using a scheduler instead of a `Thread.sleep(fiveMinutes)` makes sense to avoid tieing up resources unnecessarily (maybe you are holding on to a database connections or such).

Note that in that case, you'd be using a scheduler, not just `Thread#start`, so I am allowing for a rather liberal interpretation of Pattern B.

Comment: Creating a new thread for each iteration is wasteful either way - you can just call `Thread.sleep` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Well, I'd rather use a scheduler instead of long `Thread.sleeps`. That can actually reduce the number of threads used if I have multiple of these things running at the same time (they can all share one thread maybe). Not that creating a thread every five minutes is all that wasteful.

Comment: Absolutely, but calling `new Thread(this).start()` and then letting the current thread die is weird, wasteful and unnecessary regardless of how often you do it.

Comment: Yes. Like I said, I am allowing for a more liberal interpretation of Pattern B that will actually look more like `scheduler.schedule(new MyRunnable(), everyFiveMinutes)` with the exit condition being externalized as a `scheduler.shutdown()`. All I'm saying is "you need to have some rather special needs before a simple loop is not good enough anymore" and "there are fancy tools for those needs, so you don't just do Thread#start"

Comment: Using thread creation as an alternative to `sleep()` is a _good_ use-case?

Comment: @jameslarge: Sure. If you have ten periodic jobs that need to do something short every five minutes, then using a scheduler to put them on one single thread instead of having ten threads sleeping 99% of the time seems like a good idea.

Comment: Oops!  I totally misread your first sentence, "The only good use-case for Pattern B..."  I thought you were trying to imagine a reason why somebody would want to write Pattern B, and what you came up with was that some twisted soul might think of continually creating new threads just as a way to throttle the re-occurence of "//do something".  Apparently, that was a product of my _own_ twisted mind.

Answer (score 0):

They will behave very differently.

The first solution will loop until `condition` is false and then terminate.

The second solution will start a new thread and die until `condition` is false. It will likely accomplish what you want to do but it will waste a lot of resources allocating and destroying new threads.

Here's an example that loops over 5 values and prints the value and current thread name:

**Loop**:

```
Runnable loop = new Runnable() {

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        do {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), i);
            i++;
        } while(i < 5);
    }
};
loop.run();
```

> main: 0
>   main: 1
>   main: 2
>   main: 3
>   main: 4

**Threaded**:

```
Runnable thread = new Runnable() {

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), i);
        i++;
        if(i < 5) {
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }
};
thread.run();
```

> main: 0
>   Thread-0: 1
>   Thread-1: 2
>   Thread-2: 3
>   Thread-3: 4

As you can see, the threaded example prints each line on a different thread which is very wasteful and probably not what you want to accomplish.