# How does load and performance testing tools work behind the scenes?

Tags: performance, load, gatling

I recently used gatling.io for load testing my api server. During testing there were options to set for example, number of concurrent users per second.

What I do not understand is how these tools are able to generate that load. How are they able to create lets say 200 concurrent connection to my server and hit it?

I am looking for an answer describing how it is implemented, whether they use thread, socket programming etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatling uses the [Akka framework](http://akka.io/) internally where every virtual user is represented as an [Akka actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html).

Akka is a framework for **asynchronous** execution. This means we do not waste and suspend the thread waiting for the response but use it to complete other tasks - in this case of other virtual users. The time of execution is managed by the [scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html) and execution itself by the [dispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html)

Considering in some environments a single JVM thread stack can get as large as 2 Mb or even bigger creating a thread for each of 500 users would cost about 1 Gb of memory just for the threads. See [here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483105/5679537) about why creating lots of threads is a bad idea.

In conclusion, it is essential to use asynchronous programming to achieve such a high throughput of concurrent virtual users.