# When to use a Thread and when to use a Threadpool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Can anyone guide me in this Example Thread and ThreadPool What is the difference between them? Which is better to use ...? What is the drawback on ?

I used a threadpool  and  why use it in this case true or false ?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

class ThreeThread implements Runnable {

    String c;
    Semaphore s1;
    Semaphore s2;

    public ThreeThread(String s, Semaphore s1, Semaphore s2) {
        this.c = s;
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                s1.acquire();
                Thread.sleep(400);
                System.out.println(c);
                s2.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore sm1 = new Semaphore(1);
        Semaphore sm2 = new Semaphore(0);
        Semaphore sm3 = new Semaphore(0);

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        es.execute(new ThreeThread("1", sm1, sm2));
        es.execute(new ThreeThread("2", sm2, sm3));
        es.execute(new ThreeThread("3", sm3, sm1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Threads are heavy, i.e. expensive to create. You would use threads for long-lasting processes. If you have a lot of small tasks, you can use a thread pool. The pool allocates threads only once and re-uses them to avoid unnecessary thread creation. In regards to your example: please fix your indendation. Some explanation of what the program is supposed to to would be helpful. I see some synchronization between threads. You should avoid this in a ThreadPool since you may run into a thread starvation problem.

Comment: thanks for explanation but i can't understand you about fix indentation ..... ?

Comment: Take a look at your `try`-block.

Comment: The best practice is to use some framework that takes care of synchronization if it's possible.

Comment: @Turing85 *Why* is it expensive to create a new thread?

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev [Why is creating a Thread said to be expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive)

Comment: For the interested reader: The JDK team is working on an even more lightweight parallel model, called [Project Loom](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/Loom-Proposal.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the doc of [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> Thread pools address two different problems:
>
> they usually provide
> improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous
> tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead,
>
> and they provide a
> means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads,
> consumed when executing a collection of tasks.
>
> Each ThreadPoolExecutor
> also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed
> tasks.

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev I believe this question can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive

Answer (score -1):

Well, I thought that a ThreadPoolExecutor provided better performance for it manages a pool of threads, minimizing the overhead of instantiating a new thread, allocating memory...

And if you are going to launch thousands of threads, it gives you some queuing functionality you would have to program by yourself...

Threads & Executors are different tools, used on different scenarios... As I see it, is like asking why should I use ArrayList when I can use HashMap? They are different...

Answer (score -1):

when to use:
Threads: I want to manage thread creation, decide time of creation, and monitor, synchronization, thread cleanup, myself.

Executor: I want specialist/manager to perform these activities.