# Why do Java 21 virtual threads need less memory than platform threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-21, project-loom, virtual-threads

I do understand that platform threads are expensive as it needs more memory and it's prone to CPU context switching.

But in case of virtual threads where an unimaginably large number of virtual threads can be served by a handful of platform threads, doesn't the virtual threads still need memory space to passivate the context/stack and then attach it to the carrier thread?

How does it make a difference in terms of memory?

Why doesn't spinning 10000 virtual threads die out of memory while 10000 platform thread does?

Both of them need the same stack? And the context where the application related information need to be maintained, right?

Is there any extra overhead in the memory that's only applicable to the platform threads and this is the reason why we say virtual threads are "lighter" in memory? If so what's that that makes this difference?

Comment: Why 10,000 virtual threads don't exhaust memory in the way 10,000 platform threads would is recognizing that virtual threads are designed to be lightweight, with smaller stacks and reduced per-thread overhead.

Comment: Just for reference --  [Why is creating a Thread said to be expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive), it might help to understand the differences. Additionally, an async implementation similar to coroutines signals towards a *stackless threading.*

Comment: Another thing is _spinning_ a new thread. Spinning a new platform thread takes a lot of time and resources; spinning a new virtual thread - almost none. But if each of 1 million quickly and cheaply spun virtual threads will allocate in stack 100 Mb, then the JVM will die anyway.

Comment: Did you check with a profiler? It will show you the amount of memory allocated for various objects.

Answer (score 6):

> Both of them need the same stack.

Not true. In fact, that's probably the main "win" of virtual threads.

The call stack of a platform thread always must be contained within a dedicated, contiguous chunk of virtual memory--often around one megabyte, but you can specify larger if needed. That's how it works on every operating system. That's how it has always worked, ever since the idea of "call stack" was invented.

If you haven't done a careful analysis to determine exactly how much memory each of your threads really needs to hold its stack in the very deepest call, then you probably are over-allocating, just to be "on the safe side." Maybe you are over-allocating by orders of magnitude. Of course, it's only *virtual* memory, so if your program only has a few threads, no problem. But if you want to have *thousands* of *virtual* threads,... Suddenly, *problem.*

I don't actually *know* how the call stacks of java virtual threads are implemented, but I know that it is *not* in a single, contiguous allocation per thread.* So, at any given moment in time, no virtual thread has any more memory reserved for its stack than it actually needs.

*If I were implementing it, I imagine I would keep it in a linked list of heap-allocated objects. Maybe each activation record would be its own object, with a `next` field that points to the caller's activation record. Or maybe, it would be more efficient if it were allocated in larger "chunks." I wouldn't know until I tried.

Comment: What is your knowledge of virtual threads not allocating their stacks in a "single, contiguous allocation" based upon?

Comment: @igor.zh, Brian Goetz (Java Language Architect for Oracle) says, "Virtual threads...store their stack frames in Javas garbage-collected heap rather than in monolithic blocks of memory..." https://www.infoq.com/articles/java-virtual-threads/

Comment: Curious what of this preview-related blog still holds true for 21. Looks like not "there is no new `VirtualThread` base type" (unless I misread Dr. Goetz). He himself might chime in, though... But other than that, makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @igor.zh in which regard do you consider the blog’s statement wrong (or outdated)? It’s about the API, not internal classes.

Comment: @Holger, yes, you are right, `VirtualThread` is package-private and since https://github.com/openjdk/loom/commit/ae69a635bf9f8773abc72b30208e9c94dc2796f0 it is final. So, although such class exists, it is internal and not base.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any extra overhead in the memory that's only applicable to the platform threads

Yes.  A very large amount: megabytes versus kilobytes, if even that much.

This is why virtual threads are considered very cheap in comparison.