# Optimizing my thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I have an application where I use Executors for creating a thread pool.

Now, I know we can create a thread pool with n number of threads in it while creating.

But in my case I don't want the pool size to be fixed. I want the application to create more threads in the pool if the users are more and automatically reduce the pool size if the users are less.

Please tell me if I'm vague and you need more information on understanding this.

Cheers!!

Comment: *Maybe* a [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)? It would depend a lot on the work you're doing though, and for an application with servers I'm not really confident that that would fit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--).  Threads are created as needed, and if they go unused for a while, they will self-terminate.

Comment: Now how is this better than just creating new threads for all users?

Comment: If you are asking what advantages using a thread pool brings, I believe that is addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286626/what-is-the-use-of-a-thread-pool-in-java) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).  Creating Threads is expensive in terms of system resources, while reusing them is much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

In general the ExecutorService has default policies that would provide out-of-the-box values for various tuning parameters for newly created threads.

Based on my understanding of your question, IMO you can control the amount of time idle threads are allowed to live within a thread-pool by using the `setKeepAliveTime` method.

You can refer to the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setKeepAliveTime%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) for more details.

Also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) link provides good resources to read about thread pools and executors available in Java