# RxJava2 Android Schedulers.io() and Schedulers.newThread()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using RxJava2 Android Networking for network call. The problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to hit the API through `Schedulers.io()` sometimes it does not give any response whereas when I tried hitting the API with `Schedulers.newThread()` it always gives a response

`.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` AND `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33415881/3857465) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31276164/3857465) might be helpful

Comment: Please provide some code to show what your flow looks like. In general, both scheduler types should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of reasons if you didn't receive a response from the beck-end server.

Bellow i will post-you some example code for making network-call via rxJava2.
Note that the job is executed via `Schedulers.io()` and result is observerd on the main-thread. Note that `getCoinList()` should return some observable

```
service.getCoinList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<CoinList>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(CoinList coinList) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
   });
```